# Can an application control internet access on a device without root access?

Tags: android, root

I want to build an wireless application which can connect to certain wifi networks (for e.g public hotspots) and then control which application gets access to the internet (kind of a firewall) I wanted to know if this is even possible without rooting the device? AFAIK,it was not possible in the older versions but has anything changed?

Answer (score 0):

No, in order to forbid access to network for applications you need to edit `iptables` configuration, which is impossible without root access. I would be surprised if it was possible through the API or editable without superuser access.

In fact, the newer Android version gets released, the less privileges applications have. For instance the secondary storage is read-only starting `KitKat`, and that's not the only thing.

Comment: Even I was expecting that. But then how does applications like [mobiwol](http://mobiwol.blogspot.de) do it without rooting?

Comment: I never knew there were such apps. Don't know how exactly, but Mobiwol seems to filter traffic using VPN http://www.mobiwol.com/faqs.html